# the code is not properly waiting for the user's response to the permission request before proceeding with further operations.(jetpack compose)

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

```
override suspend fun toGetContactsList(
    context: Context,
    permissionState: PermissionState,
):StateFlow<List<Triple<Long,String,String>>> {
    val _contacts = MutableStateFlow<List<Triple<Long, String, String>>>(emptyList())

   permissionState.launchPermissionRequest()



    if (permissionState.status.isGranted) {
        // Observe contact changes using ContentObserver
        val contentObserver = object : ContentObserver(null) {
            override fun onChange(selfChange: Boolean) {
                _contacts.value = refreshContacts(context)
            }
        }

        context.contentResolver.registerContentObserver(
            ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
            true,
            contentObserver
        )

        _contacts.value = refreshContacts(context)

    }

    return _contacts.asStateFlow()
}
```

> my code is not waiting after it launched the request and returning emptylist() even after user clicked allow so how can I stop code to run before it gets allow permission and run if block to return the list of contacts ?